# Light moving with camera position

Tags: python, opengl, kivy, lighting, glsles

I am using kivy to implement a simple point light renderer with multi textures and normal mapping. My scene is a simple square, centered at the origin on which I do the mapping. I have 4 maps:
diffuse albedo
specular albedo
roughness map
normal map

In my python/kivy code, I set my matrices and other uniforms as follows:

```
view_mat = Matrix().look_at(self.cam_pos*math.sin(self.cam_rot),0,self.cam_pos*math.cos(self.cam_rot),0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.)
projection_mat = Matrix().view_clip(-width/height, width/height, -1., 1., 1., 10000., 1.)
light_pos = //can vary with keyboard input
model_mat = Matrix() (identity)
light_pos = (model_mat.multiply(view_mat)).normal_matrix() //Computes the inverse transpose of the upper left corner of the modelView matrix
```

The normal on my object is set to be (0,0,1) and the tangent is (1,0,0)

My fragment shader is:

```
void main() {

// Compute vertex eye space vertex, light and normal postion                                                                                                               
vec4 vertex_eye_space = view_mat * model_mat * vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
vec4 light_eye_space = view_mat * light_pos;
vec3 normal_eye_space = normalize((normal_mat * vec4(v_normal,0.0))).xyz;
vec3 tangent_eye_space = normalize((normal_mat * vec4(vec3(1.,0.,0.), 0.))).xyz;
vec3 bitangent_eye_space = normalize(cross(normal_eye_space, tangent_eye_space));
vec3 viewDirection_eye_space = normalize(-vertex_eye_space.xyz);

mat3 tbn_mat = mat3(tangent_eye_space, bitangent_eye_space, normal_eye_space);

viewDirection = normalize(tbn_mat * viewDirection_eye_space);
lightDirection = normalize(tbn_mat * (light_eye_space.xyz - vertex_eye_space.xyz));
vertexPosition = tbn_mat * vertex_eye_space.xyz;
texCoordinate = v_tc0;

vertex_normal = normal_eye_space;

gl_Position = projection_mat * vertex_eye_space;
}
```

And the associated fragment shader:

```
void main() {

vec3 light_vector = normalize(lightDirection);
vec3 view_vector = normalize(viewDirection);

vec3 normal = normalize((texture2D(nmap, texCoordinate).rgb) * 2.0 - 1.0);
vec3 halfway_vector = normalize((light_vector + view_vector));

vec4 diff = pow(texture2D(diffuse, texCoordinate), vec4(2.2));

vec3 Diffuse = diff.xyz * clamp(dot(normal, light_vector), 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(Diffuse, 1.0);

}
```

Now when I move my camera, the N.L value changes which makes no sense at all and I can't figure out what is wrong in this code despite spending days to debug it.

Comment: view_mat changes with cam_pos and light_pos changes with view_mat. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean stark. Could you give me more details?

Comment: vec4 light_eye_space = view_mat * light_pos;

Comment: And that is a problem how? I have define light_pos to be in world space.

Comment: eye_space=camera space. Once your lightPos is multiplied by viewMat, it becomes (as the name your are using suggests) in eye space.

Comment: Well that is what I'm looking to achieve. Express all my points and vectors in the same basis (eye space). Once that is done, I can transform to tangent space for normal mapping. It should in no way change the fact that my camera moving should not look like my light is moving too right?